# Why do Grails 3 unit tests throw StackOverflowError when run in GGTS (Eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, grails, grails-3.0, ggts

Whenever I try to run any unit test in GGTS even as simple as:

```
void "Test"() {
    expect:
    true
}
```

I get `StackOverflowError`. I wonder if it has something to do with `GrailsUnitTestMixin`.

I've imported my Grails 3 project as a Gradle project in my IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with Grails 3.0.4/3.0.5. The [fix will come with 3.0.6 release](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9227#issuecomment-138542954), which haven't been released yet at the time of writing.

In the meantime, anyone having problems with this can downgrade to 3.0.2 or 3.0.3, although 3.0.3 also has a bit of issue running unit tests in Eclipse, only not as critical as `StackOverflowError`. I suggest using 3.0.2 for now, though.